# Deserialize Json in mvc view

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

In controller I have

```
 public JsonResult Index()
{
    List<TutorialModel> models = new List<TutorialModel>();
    model.TitleWord = "Go";
    model.Colors = new List<bool>();
    model.Colors.Add(true);
    model.Colors.Add(false);
    model.Colors.Add(false);
    model.Colors.Add(false);
    model.PossibleAnswers = new List<string>();
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("1");
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("2");
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("3");
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("4");

    string ser = (new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(model);

    return Json(ser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And when In view I try to catch this Json result with

```
<script>
    var values = json.parse(@Model)
</script>
```

And browser shows me my serialize string. How I can deserialize this json  element and store in some variable.

My model for this Controller :

```
public class TutorialModel
{
    public string TitleWord { get; set; }

    public List<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }

    public List<bool> Colors { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your Controller, you don't need to return a `JsonResult` - unless you're calling it as an ajax method or something. In this case, try returning an `ActionResult` (or `ViewResult`) as normal. You could do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<TutorialModel> models = new List<TutorialModel>();
    //...add items to list

    return View(models);
}
```

Then in your cshtml javascript:

```
<script>
    var model = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a JsonResult so all that will be sent to the browser is your JSON, not the view you want.

You need to return a ViewResult:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    List<TutorialModel> models = new List<TutorialModel>();
    model.TitleWord = "Go";
    model.Colors = new List<bool>();
    model.Colors.Add(true);
    model.Colors.Add(false);
    model.Colors.Add(false);
    model.Colors.Add(false);
    model.PossibleAnswers = new List<string>();
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("1");
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("2");
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("3");
    model.PossibleAnswers.Add("4");

    string ser = (new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(model);

    return View("Index", ser);
}
```

Then in your view you can have:

```
<script>
   var values = JSON.parse("@Model")
</script>
```